# Where to put methods scanner concretely(Java)

Tags: java, methods, constructor, java.util.scanner, getter-setter

so my question is very short, I have a java constructor, and a java class that has to use the constructor to build an object.I need to ask the user for arguments that are required to build the object.Normally, do I put the required scanner(to make user input arguments) in the correct constructor methods or I ask these directly in the class methods thats use the constructor?For example, having construc.java(wich is the constructor)and contains methods like:¸

```
public void setNumber(int JNumber){
    if(JNumber>=0){
    Number = JNumber;
```

and a file called caller.java thats contain methods like:

```
public void add();
construc test = new construc(string,int,int,string,string);  //instance to use the constructor methods
```

So basically im wondering where to put this code part that ask for the number to assign the the object:

```
    Scanner thenum = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Entrez la quantité: \n");
    int ob1num = thenum.nextInt();
    ob1num = JNumber;
    setNumber(JNumber);
```

I am a little bit confuse in Java(and beginner).Thank you!

Comment: Normally you should ask for values in the class methods not the constructor.Constructor are meant for object initialization.

Comment: Basically construct initialize empty variable and after you fill the variable with user input?

Comment: Maybe im retarded, but I dont get what you mean."read and directly passed to construct with values. " could you show that using my code? thanks¸

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you want to use your `setNumber()` method. If you also want to use it to set numbers that are not based on the users input, putting the `Scanner` outside of the method is advised. Personally I would have the `Scanner` outside of the method to make which would make the method more versatile. If you need to scan multiple numbers, maybe put the scanning part in its own method that returns an `int` based on the users input.

```
class YourClass {
    YourClass() {
        //Initialize
        setNumber();
    }
}

public static main(String[] args) {
    //Create new YourClass object and set value from user input
    YourClass object = new YourClass();
}
```

Comment: Numbers will always be based on users input,and there will only be 1 number only.

Comment: In that case I would go with a method `setNumber()` that requests a number from the user and then sets it in one go.

Comment: so... setNumber() is actually in the constructor class.So im putting the input in the constructor?

Comment: I would prefer to call `setNumber()` in the constructor since you'd make sure the number is set before you proceed.

Comment: so basically you mean calling add() in public void setNumber(int JNumber){
    if(JNumber>=0){
    Number = JNumber;(wich is part of constructor)

Comment: I've added an example to my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

With getter and setter methods available in the MyClass.Your main class methods can read values

```
 Scanner thenum = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.print("Entrez la quantité: \n");
 int ob1num = thenum.nextInt();
```

And pass value to constructor

```
  MyClass(int JNumber,String JString){
    this.JNumber = JNumber;
    this.JString = JString;
 }
```

Comment: MyClass represent the class "calling/using" the constructor or the method in the constructor itself?(in this case,constructor method is  setNumber)